# Crystal Reports - Passing value from one parameter to another

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Crystal Version: 2008

I have 2 date parameters (start date and end date).  I want to create an initial Boolean parameter; that if, 'True' automatically sets the 2 date parameters to specific dates, if 'False' the user enters the start date and end date.

Basically, I want to create a parameter to drive another parameter.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Within Business Objects, if I set the first parameter to 'True', Business Objects will not continue, until I enter a start date and end date.  Any work around with this?

Comment: I don't think it will allow you to pass in an empty date, but please see the update to my previous answer.

Comment: I ended up hard coding the start and stop dates, and in the drop down, for True, I put "Leave Dates Alone" and for False, I put "Change dates below".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to use shared variables to accomplish this. You can set the values in a formula field the report header and then use the shared variables (instead of the date parameters) in your formulas.

I don't believe this will work for your main reports selection criteria though. To use it in that method you'd have to select all of the comparison data and suppress the data that you don't want to see at print time.

***Update***: My previous answer was directed to your specific question, but after reading your comment I think you should try to do what Craig is referring to. It sounds like you simply want to allow the user to run the report for either one date or for a range of dates. Instead of passing a boolean value that would handle this you should simply use a date parameter that has the following setting set:

> allow multiple values
>
> allow discrete values
>
> allow range values

Then you can use the parameter in your formulas and selection criteria which will allow the use to specify the date or the date range that the user wishes to use.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach: [Crystal Reports: Named-Date-Range Parameters](http://cogniza.com/wordpress/2005/11/24/advanced-parameter-usage-in-crystal-reports/)

Comment: I agree that if you can use a date range parameter instead of two different parameter fields then that would be your best bet, but to answer your specific question I think a shared variable would be the way to go. Thanks Craig for providing a better approach.