# Pass parameter value to another parameter

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I'm at my wits end with this.

Is there a way to assign a parameter to another parameter in Crystal Reports?

For example: MyPara_1 = MyPara_2

MyPara_2 is used in a storedproc.

Comment: see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191975/crystal-reports-passing-value-from-one-parameter-to-another

Comment: what is the exact requirement? where in the crystal report are you trying to assign?